# Prove that $(\mathbb{R^+} \times \mathbb{R^+}, \oplus)$ is a commutative group, where $(a,b) \oplus (c,d) = (ac, bd)$

Tags: group-theory

Prove that $(\mathbb{R^+} \times \mathbb{R^+}, \oplus)$ is a commutative group, where $(a,b) \oplus (c,d) = (ac, bd)$.

I had this written up but not sure if there needs to be more done. Thanks.

Let $(a,b),(c,d)$ belong to $(\mathbb{R^+} \times \mathbb{R^+}, \oplus)$. Then $(a,b) \oplus (c,d) = (ac,bd)$, which also belongs to $(\mathbb{R^+} \times \mathbb{R^+}, \oplus)$, and hence $(\mathbb{R^+} \times \mathbb{R^+}, \oplus)$ is closed under addition.

We will now show it is closed under commutative addition.
Since $(\mathbb{R^+} \times \mathbb{R^+}, \oplus)$ is closed under addition, then $(ac,bd) = (a,b) \oplus (c,d) = (c, d) \oplus  (a, b) = (ca, db)$, hence commutative addition holds for $(\mathbb{R^+} \times \mathbb{R^+},\oplus)$

Comment: "closed under commutative addition" isn't a thing. You need to prove that the set is closed under the "addition", that "addition" is commutative, that it is associative, that there is a neutral element, and that every element has an inverse. You have shown the first two of these properties. I trust you won't have any troubles with the other three, but you need to do them.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to find inverses for $(a,b)$ and you forgot to find an identity, you also forgot to prove the operation is associative. Also note this method for creating a new group from two old ones can be generalized and is called the direct product (sometimes called direct sum when working with abelian groups).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check whether it is a [group](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Group.html). Just checking closure under addition is not enough. First closed under addition (done), second associativity ($(ab)c=a(bc)$), then existence of identity ($(1,1)$), then existence of inverse ($(a^{-1},b^{-1})$).

Communitivity is OK, but it seems not to be the natural way people write. $(a,b) \oplus (c,d) = (c, d) \oplus  (a, b)$ is derived by $(ac,bd) = (ca, db)$, but you directly put $(a,b) \oplus (c,d)$ and $(c, d) \oplus  (a, b)$ on two sides of same equal mark. so I guess you are not very understanding what you are writing.

Comment: Tiny nitpickery: you don't have to explicitly check non-emptiness; the existence of an identity already guarantees that.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki Well, it is just a habit that my instructor "forces" us to have. :) I'll edit to reduce confusion. Thanks.

Comment: A little confused about the existence of an inverse, explain this a little more?

Comment: @Pasie15 Since $(1,1)$ is the identity (check it), then $(a,b) \oplus (a^{-1},b^{-1}) = (aa^{-1},bb^{-1}) = (1,1)$. Cheers! BTW $a^{-1},b^{-1} \in \Bbb R^+$ indeed.